# Weird special characters from legacy JSP code %%BSP

Tags: jsp, utf-8, special-characters

I am working with some old JSP code from ages ago and I see a string which is encoded with some special characters which I have never seen before and no matter which Javascript function I use

```
unescape(str)
```

or

```
decodeURI(str)
```

none of these commands seem to decode the string right. This is the string I get from the JSP

```
%%BSPLAKE%%BSPMICHIGAN%%BSP
```

I'm expecting it to decode to

```
LAKE MICHIGAN
```

Any idea how to decode this string?

Comment: Please share `str` as well as its [raw hex/unicode](https://mothereff.in/js-escapes) in your [mcve].

Comment: str is %%BSPLAKE%%BSPMICHIGAN%%BSP as described above in the post.

Comment: You could use the  Java String method  split  and use %%BSP  for the delimiter.

Comment: That would be an easy way out. This is just a sample test string which shows the %%BSP character set. I am trying to identify a larger pattern on how this was encoded so I can find a solution for any special characters this generates.

Comment: Why the `utf-8` tag? No UTF-8 is involved here. Where in your expected output comes the whitespace from - have you considered that BSP stands for "blank space" and such tokens are prefixed by `%%`?